# Where should I place my JS code that interacts with the database

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, file

Alright, so ive been fiddling around with Spring Boot recently and built a pretty cool backend.  I got a pretty good hang of it, I want to start to mess around with the front end more.  So, I want to create a main feed that dynamically updates based on whats in my sql database.  It will load a few objects/comments as I get closer to the bottom of the page.  Something like the function of reddits system of its main feed.  So I know I need to use JavaScript to implament the objects and I cant just use thymeleaf because thymeleaf creates the html on startup.  I noticed JQuery and it seems cool but I was thinking, it seems like people put their calls to the server get requests in the public/resources folder.  This includes the connection to the database.  That just doesnt seem right to me at all, why would you want it to be public?  And if it doesnt have to be public how do I do so.

So in summery: How do I server JS files that connect and use my database that can dynamically update my webpage.  Also any recomendations on what to use?

Comment: Well depending on how you keep each post unique in relation of loading the other comments you could use `javascript` to listen for a scroll event and use that `unique ID` to trigger a `ajax` call to then dynamically create more results. What you are wanting is very possible but many different ways can be used to achieve this depending on your current setup or plans.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  So I looked into it and ajax is exactly what I am looking for.  Found out that its a type of porcedure and not like an api.  Im researching the possibilities that I can use.  I see that php is an option but do you have any preferences or recomendations?

Comment: `php` is just a common server-side languaged used to communicate with your database. If you are new to all of this then I could continue to follow the path you have found. I use `php`  and `mysqli` for simple things like this. For more live events I use sockets.

Comment: So I ended up using JQuery and it works great now!  To be honest I dont really like php, its just a preference haha.  Thanks for bringing the idea of ajax though!  That really set me on the path.  I ended up using JQuery to call a get request which got a json object of which I used to create an html element.  I know I can also call a scroll function to it.  Thanks though!